# Merging String Lists

Tags: c#, string, list, merge

guys.

I have three string lists like that:

```
list1         list2         list3
[0]xxx25,     [0]48,yyy     [0]95,www
[1]xxx36,     [1]25,yyy     [1]75,www
[2]xxx95,                   [2]36,www
[3]xxx48,        
[4]xxx75,
```

I want to end up with list1 like that:

```
list1
[0]xxx25,yyy
[1]xxx36,www
[2]xxx95,www
[3]xxx48,yyy
[4]xxx75,www
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Is it pure list of strings manipulation ? Can you play with dictionaries instead maybe ?

Comment: strings manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

well, I don't really understand how you structure your lists, but you could do something like that :

```
foreach(string line in list1)
{
   string indice = line.Replace("xxx","");//sets which index you are looking for (i.e "25,")
   bool indiceFound=false;
   foreach(string line2 in list2)
   {
      if(line2.StartsWith(indice))//if index is found
      {
         string stringToAdd = line2.Replace(indice,"");//set what to add to the line
         line+=stringToAdd;//then add it to the original line
         indiceFound=true;//indicate you found it, so you don't nees to look in list3
         break;
      }
   }
   if(!indiceFound)
   {
      foreach(string line3 in list3)
      {
         if(line3.StartsWith(indice))
         {
            string stringToAdd = line3.Replace(indice,"");
            line+=stringToAdd;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I built a solution that would use dictionaries. In the end, from my POV, it's all about defining the dictionaries that you will need to use to define your final list.

```
private static List<string> GetMergedArrays(List<string> list1, List<string> list2, List<string> list3)
{
    var dict1 = list1.ToDictionary(key => key.Substring(3), e => e);
    var dict2 = list2.ToDictionary(key => key.Split(",")[0], e => e.Split(",")[1]);
    var dict3 = list3.ToDictionary(key => key.Split(",")[0], e => e.Split(",")[1]);

    //Merge list2 and 3
    var dict2_3 = dict2.Concat(dict3).GroupBy(k => k.Key)
                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First().Value);

    var result = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in dict1)
    {
        result.Add($"{item.Value},{dict2_3[item.Key]}");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XusbnD

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the solution by @Julien. At each step, I have added comments and console output to see the transformations. You can simplify this by removing all the commenting and output once you understand what is going on. This example first creates a single list from list2 and list3, and then iterates through it to split the strings, in contrast Julien's approach which splits twice to create dictionary key and value pairs and then merges the two dictionaries.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list1 = new List<String> { "xxx25", "xxx36", "xxx95", "xxx48", "xxx75" };
    var list2 = new List<String> { "48,yyy", "25,yyy" };
    var list3 = new List<String> { "95,www", "75,www", "36,www" };

    // Strategy: Consolidate to a single list.
    var tempList = new List<String>(list2);
    tempList.AddRange(list3);

    Console.WriteLine("Result of merging lists 2 and 3.");
    // tempList.ForEach(element => Console.Write("\"" + element + "\""));
    Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", tempList.ConvertAll(s => "\"" + s + "\"").ToArray()) + " }");

    // Strategy: Map split strings to list and then map entry.
    var dictionary =
        tempList.ConvertAll(s => s.Split(",").ToList())
            .ToDictionary(x => x.First(), x => x.Last());

    Console.WriteLine("\nOutput to show the result of converting each item to a key/value mapping.");
    Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", dictionary.Select(keyValuePair => "{" + keyValuePair.Key + ": " + keyValuePair.Value + "}")) + " }");

    // Strategy: Convert list1 values by 1) getting the last 2 digits, looking up their
    // value (e.g, 25 -> yyy), and joining the two with a comma in between.
    var result =
        list1.ConvertAll(element =>
            // User Regex.Match(...) to make the code more generic: i.e., keys with any number of digits
            // element + "," + dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(element.Substring(element.Length - 2))
            element + "," + dictionary.GetValueOrDefault(Regex.Match(element, @"\d+").Value)
        );

    Console.WriteLine("\nFinal result: ");
    // ConvertAll to put double quotes around each value to demarcate each string in the resulting list.
    Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", result.ConvertAll(s => "\"" + s + "\"").ToArray()) + " }");
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Result of converting arrays 2 and 3 to lists and merging them.
{ "48,yyy", "25,yyy", "95,www", "75,www", "36,www" }

Output to show the result of converting each item to a key/value mapping.
{ {48: yyy}, {25: yyy}, {95: www}, {75: www}, {36: www} }

Final result: 
{ "xxx25,yyy", "xxx36,www", "xxx95,www", "xxx48,yyy", "xxx75,www" }
```

The above code assumes that the numeric key is just two digits and will break if you have codes with more digits: e.g., "xxx225" and "225,aaa". To cover such cases, you would change `element.Substring(element.Length - 2)` to `Regex.Match(element, @"\d+").Value`. (You would have to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of this code unit for the compiler to recognize `Regex`).